# python mysql can't catch the exception

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

This is my code

```
self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='SomeUser', passwd='MySecruitPassword', db='scrapy', host='MySecruitHost', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(""" My secruit query """)))
            self.conn.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            errorMessage = "Error on {0} : {1}".format(e.args[0], e.args[1])
            self.sendEmail(errorMessage, "MySQL Exception 1")
        except Exception as ee:
            errorMessage2 = "Error on {0}".format(str(ee))
            print errorMessage2
            self.sendEmail(errorMessage2, "MySQL Exception 2")
```

I already know the exception, why it is happening, and how to solve it. However, I am trying to catch it.

as you see, i did two level of `try` and `catch`, and yet, my **custom** error message is not appearing. I just got exception states that there is an exception when trying to connect to my mysql in this line of code `MySQLdb.connect(...` , but i don't get my **custom** error message.

may you help please?

i am using python 2.7 on windows 7 and 64 bit

Comment: You don't have `MySQLdb.connect()` inside of a `try:`, which appears to be where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the exception is raised by the `MySQLdb.connect()` method, you should include it in the `try .. except` code block.